# POST method not working in a JSF website using Python-requests

Tags: python, rest, jsf, python-requests

I want to make an POST method in [SIGAA UnB](https://sigaa.unb.br/sigaa/public/turmas/listar.jsf) equivalent to "Choose an Department, Year, and Graduation and press *Search*".

I used Mozilla Web Inspector to see details of the refered POST request. Copied it head and body, extracted IDs and Cookie Sessions and exported the HTML response to a file. Everytime I try this, I only get the standard page, as if the post method did not work. Could someone please explain what is missing here?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS4 
import requests

page = requests.Session()

# GET Method to search for Cookies and IDs
answer = page.get("https://sigaa.unb.br/sigaa/public/turmas/listar.jsf?aba=p-ensino")
my_cookie = answer.cookies
j_id = BS4(answer.text, "html.parser").find(id="javax.faces.ViewState")["value"]

post_header = {
    "Host": "sigaa.unb.br",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Content-Length": "194",
    "Origin": "https://sigaa.unb.br",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Referer": "https://sigaa.unb.br/sigaa/public/turmas/listar.jsf?aba=p-ensino",
    "Cookie": str(my_cookie["JSESSIONID"]),
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
    "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
}

post_form = {
    "formTurma": "formTurma",
    "formTurma:inputNivel" :    "G",
    "formTurma:inputDepto" :    "673",
    "formTurma:inputAno" :  "2023",
    "formTurma:inputPeriodo" :  "1",
    "formTurma:j_id_jsp_1370969402_11" :    "Buscar",
    "javax.faces.ViewState": str(j_id),
}

answer = page.post("https://sigaa.unb.br/sigaa/public/turmas/listar.jsf?aba=p-ensino", data=post_form, headers=post_header, cookies=my_cookie)
profile_file = open("sigaa.html", "w")
profile_file.write(answer.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the correct response from the server, set `javax.faces.ViewState` variable that changes in time:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = {
    "formTurma": "formTurma",
    "formTurma:inputNivel": "G",
    "formTurma:inputDepto": "643",
    "formTurma:inputAno": "2022",
    "formTurma:inputPeriodo": "2",
    "formTurma:j_id_jsp_1370969402_11": "Buscar",
    "javax.faces.ViewState": ""
}

api_url = 'https://sigaa.unb.br/sigaa/public/turmas/listar.jsf'

with requests.session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(api_url).text, 'html.parser')

    state = soup.select_one('[id="javax.faces.ViewState"]')['value']
    data['javax.faces.ViewState'] = state

    df = pd.read_html(s.post(api_url, data=data).text)[1][1:-1]
    print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Código Ano-Período                               Docente                                                       Horário Horário.1 Qtde Vagas Ofertadas Qtde Vagas Ocupadas                 Local
1     01      2022.2    TANIA CRISTINA DA SILVA CRUZ (30h)  6T1234 (25/10/2022 - 18/02/2023)  Sexta-feira 12:55 às 16:55       NaN                   40                   0  CDT - Sala Interação
2     01      2022.2  JONATHAS FELIPE AIRES FERREIRA (30h)  6T1234 (25/10/2022 - 18/02/2023)  Sexta-feira 12:55 às 16:55       NaN                   40                   0  CDT - Sala Interação
```

Comment: After analysing you code, I understood my mistake was not at *javax.faces.ViewState* at all, but in the header i was inserting on POST method. I don't know why, but your answer helped me understanding it. Thank you a lot :)